# Create a Vector of Length N of the same numbers in R

Tags: r

I need a numeric vector with 100 4.5s inside it.

Is there a way to create this vector without typing out `c(4.5, 4.5, .....)` 100 times? Thank you.

Comment: rep(4.5,100) will do it :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
rep(4.5, 100)
```

The function rep does the trick

Comment: for future readers, don't make my mistake. I read ``rep`` but typed ``repeat`` in R which caused an infinite loop.