# Create A Vector in R with size n+1

Tags: r, vector

I  want to create an integer vector in R with size n+1, but R cant understand that with "n" i mean all the natural numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think your question would be more likely to get a good answer if you could provide some clarification. There are an infinite number of natural numbers... what *exactly* do you mean by making a vector of size `n + 1` where `n` is "all the natural numbers"?

Comment: Related: [Create a Vector of Length N of the same numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435263/create-a-vector-of-length-n-of-the-same-numbers-in-r)

Comment: I am asked to fix a integer vector a = (a0, a1, ..., an) with size n+1. Just that for the start. And then with this vector i want to find a sum . But i cant imagine how to create this kind of vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
n = 1:10

my_vector <- n+1
my_vector
```

```
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: Okeyy. Thanks a lot ! I understand now that with "n" he is not talking about all the natural numbers but he is letting me to choose the numbers that i want.